# Does mac 10.3.9 support libxml2?

Tags: objective-c

Im using xpath in libxml2 for retrieving the xml data which is working fine in mac 10.6, The same code is not working for 10.3.9?
So want to know if the libxml version in 10.3.9 support XPATH?

Comment: rephrase it, so it makes sense.

Comment: I was in hurry,,,,so did not frame it properly? please respond ASAP.

Comment: and Can you please suggest me way to retrieve the System Language and System Locale in MAC 10.3.9 using Cocoa.

Comment: Thank You, Ya i did what ever you have said.....

Answer (score 0):

Well, Mac OS X 10.3.9 [does appear to come with libxml2](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-1039/); and the version it comes with [appears to have xpath](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-16/libxml2/xpath.c) support. I don't have a 10.3.9 machine in front of me, however, so I can't help you out much beyond that.

You might want to try reducing your problem down to a small sample that demonstrates the issue; the process of reducing it down might help you find your problem, but if it does not, then I would recommend posting your example here and perhaps people could help you find your problem. Without any code to look at, it can be hard to debug a problem someone else is having.